# Column Images Showing Gaps

Tags: pages

I am using Wordpress with an Avada theme. At the top of the page I have a fusion slider.
Below this I am setting up  a containers with 2 columns. For each column I have inserted an image. 
I cant work out how to get rid of the gaps on the left and right side of the images ( I need them to go to the edge of the screen ) and the gap between the fusion slider and the two images below it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either the pagetemplate called "100% width" - else you'll need to change the settings for the column, to allow it to go 100% in width - and remove the custom padding (set to 30 or 50px on each side).